# Update field of a document inside an array of arrays in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have a `Document` that has an array field called `listsOfItems`. Its contents are `Documents` and they all contain another array field called `setOfItems`, which is composed of `Document`.
So the structure is like **`listsOfItems`(Array of `Documents`)** > **`setOfItems`(Array of `Documents`)** > **`Items`(`Documents`)**

Each `Document` in **`listsOfItems`** has a **`listId`** field which is used to uniquely identify it's contents.
Each `Document` in **`setOfItems`** has a **`itemId`** field which is used to uniquely identify it's contents.

I want to change the value of a field inside a `Document` of **`setOfItems`** given the **`listId`** and **`itemId`**.
Currently, I'm trying to do it like this:

```
final var filter = Filters.and(Filters.eq("accessDetail.email", email),
                Filters.eq("listsOfItems.listId", listId),
                Filters.eq("listsOfItems.$.setOfItems.itemId", itemId));
final var updateQuery = Updates.set("listsOfItems.$.setOfItems.obtained", BsonBoolean.TRUE);

usersCollection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, updateQuery)
```

**The query doesn't match any `Document`**
I cannot access the elements in the **`setOfItems`** by directly accessing them by index because they are ordered by other indexes and not according to their `itemId` field.

**What is the right query for performing the update given the condition?**

**EDIT1**
I have replaced my `filter` to:

```
 final var filter = Filters.and(Filters.eq("accessDetail.email", email),
                Filters.elemMatch("listsOfItems",
                        Filters.eq("listId", listId)),
                Filters.elemMatch("listsOfItems.setOfItems",
                        Filters.eq("itemId", itemId)));
```

Now I get the error message: **'Cannot create field 'obtained'** with the correct sub-document that it should make changes in.
The issue boils down to the `updateQuery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to make use of arrayFilters.

```
Document filter = new Document("base-doc-field","<value>");//query for base doc 
   //fields if any

Document updateDoc = new Document("$inc",
     new Document("listOfItems.$[elem].setOfItems.$[elem1].fieldName","value to  
        update"));


 //prepare array filters.
  List<Bson> arrayFilters = new ArrayList<>();
  arrayFilters.add(new Document("elem.listId","<list_id>"));
  arrayFilters.add(new Document("elem1.itemId","<item_id>"));

 //prepare update options, and set these array filters to update options.
 UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions().
                  arrayFilters(filterArr).bypassDocumentValidation(true);

 //execute update method.
 collection.updateOne(filter,updateDoc,options);
```

Visit https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-nested-arrays-in-conjunction-with